# Three.js Mesh Unexpected Rotation Behaviour (Global not Local Rotation)

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, transform

I was using [Three.js](https://threejs.org) to make a mesh that could be rotated via keyboard controls. However, the mesh was not rotating in the direction I intended, no matter which axes I rotated around.

Specifically, **if I rotated the mesh around one axis (Y), then I couldn't get it to rotate around another axis (X) as expected.**

Here is the code I used. Specifically note the code to rotate the cube: `mesh.rotation.x += 0.03;`

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {
        // Camera setup
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.set( 1, 2, - 2 );
    
    // Scene setup
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        // Cube Setup
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    mesh.rotation.y = 0.5;
    scene.add( mesh );
    
    // Add grid and axes
    scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( 4, 10 ) );
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper() );

        // Add renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
    // Cube doesn't rotate around local x axis
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.03;
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Here is what I tried to debug

- I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348202/three-js-global-rotation) on global rotation vs. local rotation, but the answers used `THREE.Group()` which I wasn't using.
- I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252223/adding-local-rotation-to-global-rotation) on combining global and local rotation, but the answers used rotation matrices which I wasn't using.
- I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907293/three-js-rotate-object3d-around-y-axis-at-it-center) on using the `Object3D.rotateOnAxis()` method. But that didn't work for my application because the method always created an axis from the origin to the position of my mesh. But I also wanted to translate my mesh to different positions, not just rotate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was the code that I used to rotate the cube (`mesh.rotation.x += 0.03;`) modified the global rotation, not the local rotation.

I instead **need to use the `Object3D.rotateX()` method to rotate an object locally**

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjxz6v0m/40/) and an updated code snippet with the modified rotation code. Click the button in the top left to compare local vs. global rotation.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh;
var local = false;

init();
animate();

function init() {
        // Camera setup
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.set( 1, 2, - 2 );
    
    // Scene setup
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        // Cube Setup
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    // Note: Until the mesh is rotated, global and local rotation are the same
    mesh.rotation.y = 0.5;
    scene.add( mesh );
    
    // Add grid and axes
    scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( 4, 10 ) );
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper() );

        // Add renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    // Create rotation toggle button
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = "Local Rotation Off";
    button.onclick = () => {
      local = !local
      if (local) button.innerText = "Local Rotation On";
      else button.innerText = "Local Rotation Off";
    };
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
    // This is GLOBAL
    if (!local) mesh.rotation.x += 0.03;
    // This is LOCAL
    else mesh.rotateX(0.03);
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```